# Need advice with my .asm code

Tags: assembly

Well, I have to do the assembly code of a program that checks if a "key" is valid using different checks. They way I call this asm code is via C++

```
extern "C" unsigned int EsLicenciaValida(unsigned int licencia[]);
```

lincencia is a 6 32-bits hex numbers separated by "-", for example, one that should work correctly is

```
A213457B-3746DFA3-578EC20E-4567DFF2-08A1B3AC-7B125F3A
```

the problem is I can't make it work, as far as I know the way I check everything is correct (nots, xors, ands...) but I know I'm doing something wrong with the way I move through the array and I have no clue how to fix it due to my teachers assigning things that they do not teach properly...

```
.386
.model flat, C

.code
; Completar el procedimiento
EsLicenciaValida PROC
push EBP
PUSH EBX

mov [EBP], ESP

ADD EBP, [EBP+8] 

MOV EAX, 0

;1
MOV EBX, [EBP]
NOT EBX     ;NOT TMP
MOV EAX, EBX
jmp FIN




;2
MOV EBX, [EBP+4]        ; EBX -> R2
OR EAX, EBX     ; OR TMP, R1


;3
MOV EBX, [EBP+4*2]      ; EBX -> R2
XOR EAX, EBX    ; XOR TMP, R2

;4
MOV EBX, [EBP+4*3]      ; EBX -> R3
NOT EBX     ; NOT R3
XOR EAX, EBX    ;XOR TMP, NOT(R3)
NOT EAX     ; NOT(TMP XOR NOT(R3))

;5
MOV EBX, [EBP+4*4]      ; EBX -> R4
OR EAX, EBX     ; TMP OR R4

;6
MOV EBX, [EBP+4*5] ; EBX -> R5
CMP EBX, EAX
JZ CONSECUENTE  

MOV EAX, 0
JMP FIN


CONSECUENTE:
    MOV EAX, 1  

FIN:


POP EBX
POP EBP

ret
EsLicenciaValida ENDP

END
```

Thanks in advice, I hope someone can help with with this issue.

Comment: No offence, but where are your comments? It's a rare line of assembler code that doesn't need a comment, Even rarer is a block of assembler code that doesn't need a line or two at the top explaining the overall functionality of the block.

Comment: Define _"I can't make it work"_. What is your expected result, and what is the actual result? What have you done it terms of debuggning to try to find the problem or at least isolate it?

Comment: How do you know this is wrong?

Comment: What behavior are you seeing now?  How is this different from what you expect to see?  That aside, this code looks awfully short. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you want to achieve, so I created next procedure :

- It gets an array of char as parameter.
- Checks if all characteres are valid : hyphen (-), digits (0..9), letters (A..F).
- Returns 0 (in EAX) if all characters are valid.
- Returns 1 (in EAX) when the first invalid character is found.

Next is the assembly code, pay attention to the comments, they will help you to understand how to access the array parameter and access its items:

```
.386
.model flat, C
.code
;-------------------------------------------------------
EsLicenciaValida proc

;PRESERVE EBP, ESI.
  push ebp
  push esi

  mov  eax, 0           ;RETURN VALUE (ZERO MEANS OK).
  mov  ebp, esp
  add  ebp, 12          ;GET PARAMETER'S ADDRESS.
  mov  esi, [ ebp ]     ;ESI POINTS TO ARRAY.
whil:
  mov  al, [ esi ]      ;GET CURRENT CHAR.
  cmp  al, 0            ;CHECK END OF ARRAY.
  je   finale           ;IF ( AL == 0 ) JUMP.

;CHECK IF CURRENT CHAR IS HEX (0..9,A..F).
  cmp  al, '-'
  je   its_valid        ;IF ( AL == '-' ) VALID.
  cmp  al, '0'
  jb   its_invalid      ;IF ( AL <  '0' ) INVALID.
  cmp  al, '9'
  jbe  its_valid        ;IF ( AL <= '9' ) VALID.
  cmp  al, 'A'
  jb   its_invalid      ;IF ( AL <  'A' ) INVALID.
  cmp  al, 'F'
  jbe  its_valid        ;IF ( AL <= 'F' ) VALID.
  jmp  its_invalid      ;INVALID BECAUSE AL > 'F'.
its_valid:
;NEXT CHAR TO PROCESS.
  inc  esi
  jmp  whil

its_invalid:
  mov  eax, 1           ;RETURN VALUE (ONE MEANS ERROR).
finale:

;RESTORE EBP, ESI.
  pop  esi
  pop  ebp

  ret                   ;RETURNS VALUE IN EAX.
EsLicenciaValida endp
;-------------------------------------------------------
end
```

Next is how I call it from a Visual Studio C++ console project:

```
extern "C" unsigned int EsLicenciaValida ( char * arr );
...
char arr[] = "A213457B-3746DFA3-578EC20E-4567DFF2-08A1B3AC-7B125F3A";
int x = EsLicenciaValida( arr );
```

Once you get the result in "x", you can check if it's 0 or 1 and display a message or something else. Next image shows where the assembly file is in the project:

[image]